# Looking for a CSS FIX FOR IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am doing this site for a friend http://www.kidsmartnyc.com/ and there is an enormous white space in IE8 below the middle image that is not visible in any other browser or any other version of IE. Please help, I have tried everything:)

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code here in the question?  Otherwise, once you fix the problem on the site, this question won't be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css, you defined #page1 h1 { height:250px;} .. change this...

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing a couple of things:

Like Jordy said, you set a height on your #page1 h1 tag. That's usually not necessary. The reason you're not seeing it is because the h1 tag is empty, like this:

```
<h1></h1>
```

Below that in the code, you just have a couple of 
 tags that are also creating more space. Take those out and you should be fine.